# Redirecting main site to keyword-rich subfolder for SEO

Tags: seo

I'm working on SEO for a website of local car dealer in an european no-english country. The majority of users are searching for used cars as: "car dealer volkswagen golf" and we are ranked pretty well for this because our url for cars is example.com/car-dealer/volskwagen/golf. However our domain doesn't contain any keyword and if you search for a car dealer you will never find us even though we are using this keyword on our main site pretty often (the actual keyword is with accents but users are searching without them - with accents we're on 4th page). So I was thinking to move the main site to a keyword-rich subfolder with 301 redirect -> example.com to example.com/car-dealer. Do you think it could be worthy?

I know that the value of keywords in a domain is smaller and smaller, however there is one small competitor which has never done anything for seo, he doesn't even have a description tag, he has max 5 inbound links, but his domain name is "cardealerXYZ" and he's on the first page of google results. Almost all the car dealers that are on better position have the keyword cardealer in their domain name - mostly they are not doing anything for seo - same as my client didn't.

More insights: Changing the domain name is not possible. Domain is more then 5 years old. So what do you think about just redirecting to a subfolder which contains the keyword? It could solve the problem with accents as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not 301 redirect to a new domain containing "cardealerXYZ" ? Even though yours is 5 years old, traffic (customers and robots) will follow. Keywords in the domain name are ranked way much higher than a subfolder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was recommending it but the client doesn't want it. That's why I'm thinking of at least moving the site to a subfolder with a keyword. I couldn't find any SEO experience of people doing this. Probably we will temporarily lose our PR. And yeah, I forgot to mention - all our linkbuilding is done for the core domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right. You have to move all contents of your site to "Car-Dealer" folder and create an index.htm file on root folder that will redirect your users to subfolder.

If you know programming then you can re-write URLs. Means you can create your url like this

http://yourdomain.com/best-car-dealer/cars/cars-for-sale/YOURPPAGE.html

URL rewriting is the best practices for creating search engine friendly URL.

See below example:
Actual URL: 
http://www.costumes4less.com/GroupDetail.aspx?Sku=Z804100

URL After Rewrite:
http://www.costumes4less.com/Princess-Cynthia-Child-Costume_Z804100_Prod.aspx

Second URL is Search Engine friendly but first is not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. All the URLs are rewritten with htaccess, that's why URLs of cars are looking pretty well. The only thing I'm thinking about now is to move the main page to a subdirectory only in order to have a keyword in the url. So if someone will try to access example.com he will be redirected to example.com/car-dealer. Is it worthy? Won't google mark it as spammy?

Comment: If you are using url rewriting process then you do not need to create directory just add your desired keyword in the URL. If u are satisfied the mark as answer.

Comment: Exactly, creating htaccess rule was what I meant. But will it be any positive for SEO?

Comment: absolutely its work for you. for small web up to hundreds of pages google does not mark spam.